# What would be an efficient way to select float in a finite sized array that is more close to zero?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

For each function, I get/have a finite sized array of floats that I need to pick.

So if I have something like

1)

```
 {-0.02, 0.5, 0.98, -0.15, etc... }
```

I would pick "-0.02" from this list.

2)

```
 {-0.78, 0.003, 0.1, -1.8, etc... }
```

and now, I would pick "0.003" from this list.

This is just an example. In my real program, I have floats with 5-6 decimal points.

Comment: What I tried: I made a temporary array. I went go through each elements, if it is negative, I multiply it by -1 and put them into this temporary array.
And then check for < 0. AGAIN!!! so yes, it is not efficient and I am not sure if I will lose precision too in doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) has an overload that takes a comparison function object; that's what I'd use here:

```
float val = *std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
    [](float a, float b) { return fabs(a) < fabs(b); } );
```

Comment: I am sure it might be the one I am looking for. But I am new to C++ so could explain briefly what it is doing exactly? what does the fabs() function do ?

Comment: @jbchichoko: `fabs` will return the absolute value for the given parameter (it differs from `abs` in the fact that `abs` only works on integral value, while `fabs` works exclusively on floating point values). `min_element` will return the element, which has the smallest value according to the comparison (given as third parameter of the function), so the smallest absolute value (distance from zero) in this case.

Comment: @jbchichoko: Grizzly has already answered most of your question -- just one minor addition. `std::min_element` returns an iterator to the chosen element. The `*` right before `min_element` dereferences the iterator it returns to get the value it's pointing it.

Comment: @jbchichoko Jerry Coffin's algorithm is perhaps the nicest solution, I upvoted it. However, **your program will crash if you run it on an empty array**. Make sure you it never happens in your code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Also, if I now just want the element index in that array, I am sure removing the "*" won't work, right? Still getting my heads around the min_element.

Comment: @jbchichoko: Yes -- it's an iterator, not an index. You can subtract `your_container.begin()` to get an index (assuming it's a random access iterator, which mostly translates to the container being an array, vector or deque).

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through every number on the array anyway so the most efficient answer will be in O(n).

Once you know this, you realize that just going through each number and checking if it's closer to zero that the last one you selected does the deal.

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with a compare function should archive what you want.

```
template<class T> 
const T& abs_min(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return (fabs(a) < fabs(b)) ;
}

const SIZE = 5;
float v[SIZE ] {-0.78, 0.003, 0.1, -1.8, 0.8};
float val = *std::min_element(v, v+SIZE , min_abs);
```

Answer (score 0):

- if you HAVE to use an array and it is small in size - simply iterate like `std::min_element`
- if you have freedom to pick an ordered container use `std::set<>`. then use `it=std::set::lower_bound(0)` and compare `*it` with `*(it+1)`. this would scale better for big data sizes